# JavaScript function to return only when element exists

Tags: javascript

I am working on a project that requires a dynamic page loading and also requires the function to return once the page has loaded. As it waits on certain parts of the page to load before it can execute anything else.

Currently I am using MutationObservers to detect once the elements appear. Sadly this won't allow to my knowledge for my overall function to return 'true' once the element is found.

I am using this code which after tons of looking is what seems to be what I needed for when I am checking if an element exists. But like I said won't return a value.

```
//
//MutationObserver Function : Allows for dynamic page watching without interrupting loading
(function(win) {
    'use strict';
    var listeners = [],
    doc = win.document,
    MutationObserver = win.MutationObserver || win.WebKitMutationObserver,
    observer;
    function ready(selector, fn) {
        // Store the selector and callback to be monitored
        listeners.push({
            selector: selector,
            fn: fn
        });
        if (!observer) {
            // Watch for changes in the document
            observer = new MutationObserver(check);
            observer.observe(doc.documentElement, {
                childList: true,
                subtree: true
            });
        }
        // Check if the element is currently in the DOM
        check();
    }
    function check() {
        // Check the DOM for elements matching a stored selector
        for (var i = 0, len = listeners.length, listener, elements; i < len; i++) {
            listener = listeners[i];
            // Query for elements matching the specified selector
            elements = doc.querySelectorAll(listener.selector);
            for (var j = 0, jLen = elements.length, element; j < jLen; j++) {
                element = elements[j];
                // Make sure the callback isn't invoked with the
                // same element more than once
                if (!element.ready) {
                    element.ready = true;
                    // Invoke the callback with the element
                    listener.fn.call(element, element);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // Expose `ready`
    win.ready = ready;
})(this);
```

and then I call but obviously this function returns even if company name wasn't filled in. How can I make this function wait until company name was filled in before returning

```
function fillOutInitial(){

ready("input[id='companyName']", function(element) {
  document.getElementById('companyName').value = "COMPANY NAME";});


return "companyName Completed"
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you would want to solve monitoring an input element so complicated ?

Comment: There are more inputs on the screen. Basically I need to monitor when each input is loaded and fill it in. And once we hit the last input. Move into the next screen. There are 4 screens total that it must move through. Each one is dynamically generated. So I must wait for elements to appear. If there is a better way for me to wait for each element and then return the function. I am open to suggestions. Even jQuery if I need too

Comment: Wait a minute. This code works exactly as it should.  When the input element with an ID of companyName exists in the DOM, call your function. No where do you ever check if the input has a VALUE.

Comment: The code for mintoring works. I'm not monitor for a value. I am monitoring that once the element exists. It needs to fill in a value. I run it in a function because I need to know when the element has been completed. But MutationObservers don't make returning a value easy

Comment: Oh i see.. your trying to have the fillOutInitial function wait to return until after YOU set the value. Your setting of the value must wait for the dom element to exists.

Comment: Yes exactly!! I've been struggling with this for days trying to take different approaches. From MutationObservers to setTimeOut. I'm lost on how this can be accomplished.

Comment: TBH,  your probably strggling because of the concept that you are using. Javascript is a scripting language. It's made to go X then Y then Z. The only way to do what you want is callbacks/promises. You could provide a callback to the fillOutInitial function and then execute that callback after the value is set.

Comment: Could you write a quick example? I've looked at them before. But not 100% confident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Callback and Promise example has requested by Zach. You will get an alert after 1 second indicating that the first companyName inputs exists, and the value has been set. You will get an alert after 2 seconds that says companyName2 input exists and has been set.

```js
//SAMPLE WAITING FOR INPUTS
window.setTimeout(function () {
 document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = '<input id="companyName" />'
}, 1000);
window.setTimeout(function () {
 document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = '<input id="companyName2" />'
}, 2000);



//MutationObserver Function : Allows for dynamic page watching without interrupting loading
(function(win) {
    'use strict';
    var listeners = [],
    doc = win.document,
    MutationObserver = win.MutationObserver || win.WebKitMutationObserver,
    observer;
    function ready(selector, fn) {
        // Store the selector and callback to be monitored
        listeners.push({
            selector: selector,
            fn: fn
        });
        if (!observer) {
            // Watch for changes in the document
            observer = new MutationObserver(check);
            observer.observe(doc.documentElement, {
                childList: true,
                subtree: true
            });
        }
        // Check if the element is currently in the DOM
        check();
    }
    function check() {
        // Check the DOM for elements matching a stored selector
        for (var i = 0, len = listeners.length, listener, elements; i < len; i++) {
            listener = listeners[i];
            // Query for elements matching the specified selector
            elements = doc.querySelectorAll(listener.selector);
            for (var j = 0, jLen = elements.length, element; j < jLen; j++) {
                element = elements[j];
                // Make sure the callback isn't invoked with the
                // same element more than once
                if (!element.ready) {
                    element.ready = true;
                    // Invoke the callback with the element
                    listener.fn.call(element, element);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // Expose `ready`
    win.ready = ready;
})(this);


//CALLBACKS
fillOutInitialCallback(function (someValue) {
  //Wont be called until after companyName has been set.
  alert(someValue)
});

function fillOutInitialCallback(fnCallback){
  ready("input[id='companyName']", function(element) {
    document.getElementById('companyName').value = "COMPANY NAME";
    fnCallback("companyName has been set.")
  });  
}

  
  
//PROMISES
fillOutInitialPromise().then((someValue) => {
  //Wont be called until companyName2 has been set.
  alert(someValue);
});

function fillOutInitialPromise(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ready("input[id='companyName2']", function(element) {
      document.getElementById('companyName2').value = "COMPANY NAME";
      resolve("companyName2 has been set");
    });      
  });  
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">

</div>
```